# How to get the villager Kabuki?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How will I be able to get the villager Kubiki on AC:NL?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways that villagers can move into your town.

The first is random - if you have fewer than 9 villagers in your town, the game will generate a new one to fill that empty slot within a couple days. The animal chosen is random, so it'll take a while to get the cat you want. If you'd like to increase your chances, convince the villagers you already have to move out. Here's a pretty good guide that should help: [Guide to get them out](http://www.belltreeforums.com/showthread.php?82107-Guide-Fool-Proof-Guide-to-Moving-Villagers-OUT)

The second way is through the campsite public works project. Once you build it, animals will come visit every so often and stay for a day. You can play games and buy and sell items from them, and if you have less than 10 villagers already living in your town, you can get the option to ask them to move in if you talk to them enough. Building the campsite would be wise, as it's not only fun, but will bring a bunch of campers to your town... maybe Kubiki if you're lucky!

The third way is to visit other people's towns, meet Kabuki there, and ask him to move to your town. There are people on Animal Crossing communities online that "trade" "buy" and "sell" villagers this way - finding an animal crossing forum and asking for someone who has a Kabuki in their town that's leaving will probably be the fastest way to get him. You might have to give some Bells to the other person for their trouble though.